# snap to road js fiddle

Tags: javascript, json, osrm

I would like to ask a simple question: I have a simple code in jsfiddle (in Javascript) about nearest service. More specifically, you put the coordinates and it returns the nearest coordinates to road (through Google Maps) with nearest service OSRM. This means "snap to road". How can I save theese coordinates into variables? I tried this but it doesn't work.

JavaScript in JSFiddle:

```
const url = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/';
const coord = {
    lon: 23.694516,
    lat: 38.017791
};

fetch(url + coord.lon + ',' + coord.lat).then(function(response) { 
    return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    if (json.code === 'Ok') {
        console.info(json);
        var lon=json.waypoints[0].location[0];
        var lat=json.waypoints[1].location[1];
        console.info(lat);
    }
});
```

Comment: Those variables only exist inside the function. If you want them to persist, you need to declare them outside any function.

Comment: @ChrisG how can i declare them outside the the function? thank you so much in advance! :)

Comment: @IriniK. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/c5jggmdc/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much!Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @ChrisG is there anything i can do to give you an award or something like that?